Can I fetch organization pages a user can post to without having to setup two apps in LinkedIn?
I am working on a prototype for enhancing a SaaS platform with the ability to post platform-generated images and text to LinkedIn. So far, I've setup and accomplished the following ...

Setup an app in LinkedIn with the Share on LinkedIn and Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect products.
Setup Member Authorization (3-legged OAuth Flow) within my simple prototype, (React/Vite).
Setup a mechanism for creating an organic post to a user's feed with images and text.

I would like to give the end-user the ability to post to an organization page as the organization, assuming they've been granted sufficient permissions in LinkedIn. I'm envisioning the end-user is provided with the ability to choose the destination or target for their post; e.g. a drop-down alongside a button.
So, I've begun investigating how to identify the organization pages a given user is permitted to post to.  I think the endpoint I need to utilize to get this information is under Organization Authorizations; however, in order to utilize the endpoint I will have to create a separate application. I will have to add the Community Management API product to utilize the endpoint I identified above. Unfortunately, I would have to setup a separate application as that product is required to be the only product granted to on the application.
A downside of having two LinkedIn apps is the user experience for the user.  An initial approval is required to grant the ability to authenticate and post to their personal feed.  A second app approval is required to fetch organization pages they can target, assuming there are any.
Are there other options or paths towards what I'm looking to provide which can be accomplished within a single LinkedIn app?  Am I overlooking other ways to find this information that exist outside of the Community Management API offerings?
I've explored the documentation for the LinkedIn API to identify other options.  Navigating their documentation is a touch difficult, I seem to be catching them in a transitional period between versions and groupings of capabilities.  I find interpreting the FINDER Restli queries daunting, too. I submitted a case to LinkedIn Support who redirected me to StackOverflow.
I found this question whose accepted answer provides a broken link to a v1 endpoint.  I've dismissed that option given there are v2 endpoints along with header-versioned endpoints following a different versioning format.
